# Strong and Weak encapsulation in Java

Tags: java, oop, object, computer-science

Please, tell me the difference between strong and weak encapsulation w.r.t. java language.
Encapsulation is the binding of data and its associated functions in a single unit called a class. So, what does the term mean e.g. weak and strong encapsulation?

Comment: you can refer to https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2010-December/012334.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is basic difference. It varies based on usage and view point.

Private fields are example of Strong Encapsulation.

Public fields are example of Weak Encapsulation. In this case fields are still encapsulated in the class, but visible to outside world.

Protected/default fields show moderate Encapsulation.

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulation is an OOP concept that keeps data and functions from outside interference or misuse. Encapsulation enables hiding the implementation from the client and enables changes in the code without affecting the client. The adjectives 'Weak' or 'Strong' refer to how good this concept enforced in your code.

For example, consider you have a class called `Person` which has a field called `name`. Encapsulation suggests to "hide" this field from a client of the class so he won't harm or misuse it. You can achieve such a behavior by making the `name` attribute `private` (so the only code which can refer to this attribute is the one that implementing `Person`) and provide a getter method `getName()` which will return the name property to the client. This will be considered strong encapsulation - the property isn't reachable from outside and can't be misused.

A weak encapsulation will be providing a method that as a side effect changes the state of this property and by that "exposing" the property and creates a loophole.

Answer (score 0):

Strong encapsulation means that the code implementing an abstraction can
control the visibility of its fields (i.e. where they can be accessed
from), without any loopholes that can be exploited by code outside the
abstraction's scope. Weak encapsulation allows such loopholes.

Answer (score 0):

Strong Encapsulation means a class that contains all property access levels as private & every method as a public. Then that satisfies the Strong Encapsulation and then that class is called as Strong Encapsulation class.
Through Strong Encapsulation we can’t access any properties directly outside from the class.If want to access or initialize the value to the properties. Then we should run through public method.
Weak Encapsulation is like if class contain any property access level other than private and method access level other than public. Then that class is called as Weak Encapsulated class.

Answer (score 0):

`private & geterMethod` = Strong encapsulation

`private & seterMethod` = Weak encapsulation